# How to set number of clusters in Kohonen SOM in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I have a data set and want to cluster by Kohonen SOM in R. I want to vary number of clusters from 2 to 40, but I didn't find package, where I can set the number of clusters before clustering, as parameter.

Can you help me to find appropriate package or library or tool, where I can set the number of clusters of Kohonen SOM, as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOM is a model for data visualization/feature mapping in wich you reduce the dimensionality of your data to 1/2/3 dimensions by learning the topology of the input space with a neural-network of regular shape.

You can perform clustering on the space learned by a SOM using classical algorithms, or visually inspect the U-Matrix

Take a look [here](http://www.generation5.org/content/2004/aiSomPic.asp), [here](http://www.peltarion.com/doc/index.php?title=Self-organizing_map), or [here](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html),  for other info.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine xdim and ydim of the som function : 
xdim an integer specifying the x-dimension of the map. 
ydim an integer specifying the y-dimension of the map.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion for SOM clustering (hierarchical) could be according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935020/out-of-bound-error-in-self-organising-maps-som) answer.

Modyfying @Andrew Gustar's answer:

```
som_cluster=cutree(hclust(object.distances(Add_your_SOM_object_here,"codes")), 4)
```

Where Add_your_SOM_object_here is the Kohonen SOM object, and number four is the number of clusters.