# Out of bound error in Self-Organising Maps (SOM)

Tags: r

I have a big dataset "nm":

```
dim(nm)
[1] 3871012      13
```

I am trying to plot Self-Organising Maps (SOM) on that data:

```
library(kohonen)

som_grid = somgrid(xdim = 20, ydim=20 , topo="hexagonal")

zx = as.matrix(nm)

som_model = som(zx,
                grid=som_grid,
                rlen=100,
                alpha=c(0.05,0.01),
                keep.data = TRUE)

som_cluster = cutree(hclust(dist(as.numeric(unlist(som_model$codes)))), 4)

plot(som_model, type="codes", bgcol=rainbow(4)[som_cluster])
```

Upto this code works fine but when I add cluster boundaries following error appears:

```
add.cluster.boundaries(som_model, som_cluster)
Error in nb[i, 1] : subscript out of bounds
```

I am not sure how to rectify this error or am I doing something wrong.

Kindly provide solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `som_cluster` - your method produces a vector that is longer than the number of units in `som_model`.  Try the following instead...

```
som_cluster = cutree(hclust(object.distances(som_model,"codes")), 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for solution !!